# Can I control the sensitivity of the back gesture on the Magic Mouse?

Tags: macos, mac, mouse

So I stopped working from home last month and took my beloved Logitech to the office, which means I'm stuck with the horrendous Magic Mouse here at home now.

Whenever I'm wanting to go back in Firefox, the slightest two-fingered left gesture sends it spinning back about a dozen pages.

Any way around that, short of using Safari?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com)? You can use it to adjust the tracking speed, per their documentation.

> Fine tuning tracking speed
>
> MagicPrefs does not have available in the interface the fine tune tracking speed settings from the apple control panel, however they can be set manually by entering the next command in Terminal.app (change 0.3125 to your desired speed)
>
> defaults write com.vladalexa.MagicPrefs TrackingMouse -float 0.3125
>
> defaults write com.vladalexa.MagicPrefs TrackingTrackpad -float 0.3125
>
> The Apple Tracking speed slider for the Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad has 10 speed settings : 0.0, 0.125, 0.3125, 0.5, 0.6875, 0.875, 1.0, 1.7, 2.0, 3.0
>
> The MagicPrefs Magic Mouse tracking speed slider has 10 speed settings : 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0
>
> The MagicPrefs Magic Trackpad tracking speed slider has 10 speed settings : 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0